# Android ListView Load More Items With Loader Manager

Tags: android, listview, android-loadermanager

I have just created a ListView and wishes to implement a load more messages button. The data should be sorted in a descending order according to the date of the messages. Thus, I created a few variables:

```
        mInitialTotalMessages = Message.getTotalImages(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), messageID);
        mHasMoreRecord = mInitialTotalMessages > (MESSAGE_LIST_PAGE_SIZE * mPageNo);
        mOffset = (int)mInitialTotalMessages - (MESSAGE_LIST_PAGE_SIZE * mPageNo);
        mOffset = (mOffset < 0) ? 0 : mOffset;
```

When there is more messages the loader will restart and query more messages. I have included in Offset in my query to limit my data displayed according to the variables set. But here comes my questions. How do I display the data in a descending order and ensures that the data are not displayed until the user pressed the load more button? Below are my queries to retrieve my messages.

1. This is my first SQL query:

   ```
   String sortQuery = TableMessage.MESSAGE_DATE + " ASC LIMIT -1 OFFSET " + mOffset;

   String selection = TableMessage.MESSAGE_ID+ " = ?";

   String[] selectionArgs = {messageID};

   return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), ContentProviderMessage.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
   ```

I managed to get the last 2 items but how do I reverse the orders in the ListView.

[Image for Query 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTQwn.png)

2. This is my second SQL query:

   ```
   String sortQuery = TableMessage.MESSAGE_DATE + " DESC LIMIT -1 OFFSET " + mOffset;

   String selection = TableMessage.MESSAGE_ID+ " = ?";

   String[] selectionArgs = {messageID};

   return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), ContentProviderMessage.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
   ```

The data retrieved are Data 1 and Data 2. How do I get Data 5 to Data 3.

[Image for Query 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgsDm.png)

Please advice.

Thank you.

Comment: post ContentProviderMessage code

Comment: @pskink,

Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

return cursor;

Thank you.